# comparing a string in MIPS

Tags: converters, mips, roman-numerals

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code so far. I am trying to make a program that takes input from the user (roman numerals) and then converts it to integers. So far this is what I have:

```
.data
buffer: .space 20
onlyCaps: .asciiz "Please enter only Capital Numbers\n"
enter1: .asciiz "Number out of range. Please enter another number\n"
enter2: .asciiz "Please enter your roman numeral: "
debug:  .asciiz "reach"
M:  .asciiz "1000"
D: .asciiz "500"
C: .asciiz "100"
L:  .asciiz "50"
X: .asciiz "10"
V:  .asciiz "5"
I: .asciiz "1"

.text

main:
la  $a0, onlyCaps   # "Enter Only Capital numbers"
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la  $a0, enter2     #prompt user with "Please enter a roman numeral:"
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, buffer      #load byte space into address
li $a1, 3           # allot the byte space for string

li $v0, 8           #read user input, j
syscall

li $t4, 1

loop:
lb $t0, 0($a0)   # Save $v0 value to $t0
beqz $t4, done   # if it is equal to zero end the loop
add $a0, $a0, $t4   #increment the address
j mCheck

#while loop ends here

mCheck:
beq $t0, 'M', mChar  # if $t0 equal M go to mChar
bne $t0, $t1, dCheck  # move to see if equals D

dCheck:
beq $t0, 'D', dChar  # if $t0 equal D go to dChar
bne $t0, $t1, cCheck

cCheck:
beq $t0, 'C', cChar  # if $t0 equal C go to cChar
bne $t0, $t1, lCheck

lCheck:
beq $t0, 'L', lChar  # if $t0 equal L go to lChar
bne $t0, $t1, xCheck

xCheck:
beq $t0, 'X', xChar  # if $t0 equal X go to xChar
bne $t0, $t1, vCheck

vCheck:
beq $t0, 'V', vChar  # if $t0 equal V go to vChar
bne $t0, $t1, iCheck

iCheck:
beq $t0, 'I', iChar  # if $t0 equal I go to iChar
bne $t0, $t1, error

mChar:   
la  $a0, M      #puts one hundred in $t3          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

dChar:   
la  $a0, D      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

cChar:   
la  $a0, C      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

lChar:   
la  $a0, L      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

xChar:   
la  $a0, X      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

vChar:   
la  $a0, V      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

iChar:   
la  $a0, I      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

error:  
la  $a0, enter1     # Print error meg. then back to main
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   done

done:   
li  $v0, 10         # Exit
syscall
```

My question is how can you take input from the user and put it in `$a0`, and then use a while loop after that? I can't get the bytes to go to the next spot (i.e. `MXX` to go from `M` to `X`.) currently the program reads `M`, but not `X`. Eventually I will switch the program to sum these numbers and to also check to see if the number before is less (i.e. `IV`) to account for those roman numerals but I need help with the while loop first.

Comment: `move    $t0, $v0    # Save $v0 value to $t0` <-- the string contents are in `buffer`, not in `$v0`.

Comment: So it should be:  move $t0, buffer #save buffer to $t0?

Comment: try `lb $t0,0($a0)`.  The address of buffer is already in `$a0`, and this reads the first byte of buffer into `$t0`, where it can be compared with the "M" in `$t1`.

Comment: @markgz i updated my code. could you take a loop and see if you could figure out the while loop i am having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know what the question is

Comment: I am trying to get my while loop to work. currently it read the first letter M (MXXI), but ends before it reads X. Is there a way in mips to iterate through to the next character and then compare it to my "if" statements?